# Redirect url on local host

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building a react native app. I am using expo and on to develop de application. On my host machine I have an API on the url api.myapp.test.

When I do a fetch to that url from my react app. I get an error:

> [23:07:28] Network request failed
>   - node_modules/whatwg-fetch/fetch.js:439:29 in onerror
>   - node_modules/event-target-shim/lib/event-target.js:172:43 in dispatchEvent
>   - ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals

I have the feeling that my app or local host does not know where to route this url to.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the url api.myapp.test is registered in your host's DNS resolver (which in turn resolves it to "localhost"). The dns resolver used by Expo is the one of the phone, and it has no clue about api.myapp.test.

The quickest solution is to refer directly to the api from the app by using the IP of your host in your network (this is only feasibily in development, if you release your application you will have to move your API to a public domain).